# Attempting a powershell folder loop & edit with the foldername as a string

Tags: powershell

I have several hundred  folders all with different but exact names.
Example  :      C:\test\1011
C:\test\1012
C:\test\1013
C:\test\1014   and so on

Inside each folder there is exactly 1  file. The same file name in each folder.
info.xml

I need to change 1 node inside each .xml file in every folder.
the node is currently       0000

I need it be      1011 (based on the folder name the file resides in).
1012  etc.

So a recursive XML edit that reads the folder name & alters the node to match.

Thanks

I have gotten this far

```
 $folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path  C:\Test -Recurse | 
 select -expand fullname
 ForEach ($folder in $folders){
  $FolderName=$_.Name |
   Get-Item .\info.xml |
    % { $_.Replace("0000", "$_.Name") } | 
      Set-Content .\info.xml }
```

Comment: "the node is currently 0000" can be interpreted a number of ways, please show an actual sample XML file

Comment: 'code'   <metadata>
   <assetID>0000</assetID>   
  </metadata>
 </assetPackage>